# tf.train.batch output is not deterministic

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow for learning MNIST data.
For batching I create a batch from single images like this:

```
BatchedInputs = list(tf.train.batch(
  Inputs,
  batch_size=BatchSize,
  num_threads=self._PreprocessThreads,
  capacity=self._MinimumSamplesInQueue + 3 * BatchSize))
```

When I create (for testing) batches of size 1 and look at those images in TensorBoard, I can see that not in every run, every image is the same like in other runs.
They are not directly shuffled, but sometimes another image is contained.

I would expect to get a deterministic output from that operation, but this is not the case. Maybe I'm doing anything wrong (starting queues wrong or something like that)?

Comment: Another note: When I do not batch the data, but simply provide the list `Inputs` to my network, the input data is deterministic in all runs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set `num_threads > 1` when calling [`tf.train.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch), the resulting program will be non-deterministic, because this will create three uncoordinated prefetching threads that evaluate `Input` and insert the next element into the queue. Since the prefetching threads are uncoordinated, there is a race between these threads to enqueue elements in the queue, and this leads to the non-determinism in the order of queue elements.

Setting `num_threads = 1` should make this part of your program deterministic, assuming that the other parts of your program are deterministic. However, this is a weak guarantee, and—in particular—any use of shuffling in the queue-based input routines will make the program non-deterministic.

Comment: Indeed, I use 8 thread for pre-fetching. Reducing the number to 1 will solve the issue!
Thanks for that clear explanation.